# Importing database schema in PostgreSQl fails

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu

So I want to import a database schema but it fails. PostgreSQL Version is 9.5.11. Maybe the command is outdated? The user "user" is already set up. Do I need to pass a password additionally in the command?

```
postgres@root:~$ psql -d database -U user -f createdb.sql
psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "user"
```

Comment: You should check you `pg_hba.conf`file.

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql by default if you connect using unix socket the authentification is done with the **peer** method, this means you must use the same login unix and postgresql user. Here you try to user the user **user** but when running psql with the unix user **postgres** so it won't work. There is many different solutions, do you action as user **postgres** under postgres and then change the ownership later, or create a unix user calles **user** and do the action with it. You may define a password for the user **postgres** and connect on the loopback too. But if you don't understand how **pg_hba.conf** works it's not a good idea to modify it.